# Determine a numeric range that may contain alpha and numeric characters

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not even sure how to phrase this question so I apologize in advance. I have a form used by our QA. it requires input of serial numbers - a lot of them (sometimes hundreds). I have two text boxes on the form for lower and upper numbers in the range (doesn't have to be this way but it is my best guess). I know how to to do this if it were just integers (see code below) but that is not the only format.Examples of the format could include a date code ("170508/1234") or could include alpha characters (ABC1234). there is a wide variety of formats but in every case, I want to find the range from the last set of numbers (typically last four digits - Like "170508/1234 170508/1235... and ABC1234 ABC1235 ... not to exclude 1234 1235 ....). 
Thank you in advance

```
 private void btnSN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int from = Convert.ToInt32(txtSnStart.Text.Trim());
        int to = Convert.ToInt32(txtSnEnd.Text.Trim());

        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) 


        {

           txtSN.Text +=  i.ToString() +" ";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of RexEx for this, the RegEx expression below should match any number of digits at the end.:

```
(\d+)$
```

Here is the modified code:

```
// find the group of digits at end of entered text
var fromMatch = Regex.Match(txtSnStart.Text.Trim(), @"(\d+)$");
int from = Convert.ToInt32(fromMatch.Groups[1].Value);

// strip the matched digit group from entered text to get the prefix
string prefix = txtSnStart.Text.Trim().SubString(0, txtSnStart.Text.Trim().LastIndexOf(from.ToString()));

var toMatch = Regex.Match(txtSnEnd.Text.Trim(), @"(\d+)$");
int to = Convert.ToInt32(toMatch.Groups[1].Value);

for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
{
    // combine the prefix and range value
    txtSN.Text += string.Format("{0}{1} ", prefix, i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks - almost there! the only thing is (and I apologize for not making this clear) I will need for it to retain the format. your code works nicely for the numeric range, I just need it to keep the characters in front when it writes to txtSN.Text

Comment: Well, say that SnStart is 'abc1234' and SnEnd is 'xyz1236', what should be the output?

Comment: the prefix would not change like that so, the input would always be abc#### or xyz####. So, to your question an example would be SnStart = abc1234 SnEnd would be abc1236, then the output would be abc1234 abc1235 abc1236

Comment: @AlanRobertson I have updated the answer to include the prefix.

Comment: thanks for the update. I am having trouble with     string prefix = txtSnStart.Text.Trim().Substring(0, txtSnStart.Text.Trim().LastIndexOf(from)) it is giving an "cannot convert from 'int' to 'char' error on (from))    I appreciate your help very much

Comment: tried from.tostring() - now it is stating var and toMatch do not exist in the current context

Comment: did the trick !! you sir are a great help and I sincerely appreciate all you did - and especially your patience.

Comment: What was the trouble with toMatch not existing? Was it the semi-colon missing at the end of previous statement?

Comment: yes (he said blushing) it was just missing the semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes easier if you break it into smaller pieces.

This will become especially important once it becomes apparent that one small part of the problem might become more complex.

The inputs are a prefix, a number to begin the range, and a number to end the range. Given that, here's a class with a function to return those strings:

```
public class StringRangeCreator
{
    public IEnumerable<string> CreateStringRange(
        string prefix, int rangeStart, int rangeEnd)
    {
        if (rangeStart > rangeEnd) throw new ArgumentException(
             $"{nameof(rangeStart)} cannot be greater than {nameof(rangeEnd)}");
        return Enumerable.Range(rangeStart, (rangeEnd-rangeStart) + 1)
            .Select(n => prefix + n);
    }
}
```

`Enumerable.Range` creates a range of numbers. The `Select` takes that range and returns a set of strings consisting of the prefix concatenated with the number in the range.

And a unit test to make sure it works:

```
[TestClass]
public class DetermineRangeFromLastFourCharacters
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ReturnsExpectedRangeOfStrings()
    {
        var result = new StringRangeCreator().CreateStringRange("abc", 1, 10).ToList();
        Assert.AreEqual(10, result.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("abc1", result[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("abc10", result[9]);
    }
}
```

But if these are serial numbers then you maybe you don't want ABC8, ABC9, ABC10. You might want ABC08, ABC09, ABC10. All the same length.

So here's the modified class. I'm guessing a little at what the expected behavior might be. It lets you specify an optional minimum number of digits so that you can pad accordingly:

```
public class StringRangeCreator
{
    public IEnumerable<string> CreateStringRange(
        string prefix, int rangeStart, int rangeEnd, int minimumDigits = 1)
    {
        if (rangeStart > rangeEnd) throw new ArgumentException(
             $"{nameof(rangeStart)} cannot be greater than {nameof(rangeEnd)}");
        return Enumerable.Range(rangeStart, (rangeEnd-rangeStart) + 1)
            .Select(n => prefix + n.ToString("0").PadLeft(minimumDigits, '0'));
    }
}
```

And another unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PadsNumbersAccordingToParameter()
{
    var result = new StringRangeCreator().CreateStringRange("abc", 999, 1001, 3).ToList();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc999", result[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("abc1001", result[2]);
}
```

Some other scenarios you might want to account for are negative numbers or extremely large ranges.

Now that the problem of creating the result set is separated into a class with simple inputs and outputs that you can test, what remains is to take the input from the form and break it down into these inputs. That might include making sure that both strings have the same prefixes and making sure that the last parts of the strings are numbers.

But the whole thing will be a little simpler once it's not all in one big method. That also makes it easier to change when you realize something different about how you want it to work. Validating your input can be one step, and then getting the results can be another.

The unit tests help because you don't want to have to debug the whole thing to see if it works. `Enumerable.Range` didn't work the way I thought it did, so I had to fix a bug. It was easy to find and fix with the unit tests. It would have been harder if I had to run a whole app and then step through it in the debugger.

Comment: These aren't exactly "model" unit tests because each one has multiple asserts (each test checks more than one thing.)